# How align 2 uibuttons programmatically in a layout?

Tags: constraints, uialertview, nslayoutconstraint

I use the [KLCPopup](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup) library to display a popup in my app.
I have to add 2 buttons horizontally on the bottom of this popup, like the standard iOS UIAlerView. I cannot align this two buttons horizontally.
Here is the result I **want**:

[image: The result I want]

But here is the result I have:
[image: The only way I could find to add this 2 buttons]

Here is the code I use to create this popup:

```
UIView* contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UILabel* dismissLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
dismissLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
dismissLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[dismissLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
dismissLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
dismissLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200;

UIButton* dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
dismissButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
dismissButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 10, 20);

[contentView addSubview:dismissLabel];
[contentView addSubview:dismissButton];

UIButton* cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
cancelButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 10, 20);

[contentView addSubview:cancelButton];

NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView, dismissButton, cancelButton, dismissLabel);

[contentView addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(16)-[dismissLabel]-(16)-[dismissButton]-(16)-[cancelButton]-(16)-|"
                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:views]];

[contentView addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(18)-[dismissLabel]-(18)-|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:views]];

// Show in popup
KLCPopupLayout layout = KLCPopupLayoutMake(KLCPopupHorizontalLayoutCenter,
                                           KLCPopupVerticalLayoutCenter);

KLCPopup* popup = [KLCPopup popupWithContentView:contentView
                                        showType:KLCPopupShowTypeFadeIn
                                     dismissType:KLCPopupDismissTypeGrowOut
                                        maskType:KLCPopupMaskTypeDimmed
                        dismissOnBackgroundTouch:NO
                           dismissOnContentTouch:NO];

[popup showWithLayout:layout];
```

I think the problem on my code is the constraint.I've tried many possibilities but I cannot find the right way to do this.

Any advice will be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: any luck figuring this out? I'm facing the exact same thing with the exact same library. =/ @barrast

Comment: Finally I used TTAlertView (https://github.com/twotoasters/TTAlertView), which was more useful for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added all three views to the vertical constraint and that's why they are all one after another. Do something like this:

```
V:|-16-[dismissLabel]
V:|-80-[dismissButton]
V:|-80-[cancelButton]
H:|-18-[dismissLabel]-18-|
H:[dismissButton(50)]-100-[cancelButton(50)]
```

I haven't tested it but something like that could work. You might have to modify the last H value or maybe add a centering option to it. There are probably better ways where you could group some of those things but this should work too.